# content-length in HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, content-length

I'm trying to send a body in `x-www-form-urlencoded` to my local Web API. I can make `GET` without any problems. Here is what I do:

```
    String urlParameters = "user=User&label=GPU+Temp&file=src%2FDataSource0.txt&backgroundColor=rgb(255%2C255%2C255%2C0)&borderColor=rgb(255%2C255%2C255%2C0)&pointBorderColor=rgb(255%2C255%2C255%2C0)&pointHoverBackgroundColor=rgb(255%2C255%2C255%2C0)&pointHoverBorderColor=rgb(255%2C255%2C255%2C0)&min=0&max=100&stepSize=50";

    byte[] postData = urlParameters.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    int postDataLength = postData.length;
    String request = "http://192.168.1.30:6262/api/values";
    URL url = new URL(request);
    con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    con.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength));
    con.connect();
```

> java.net.ProtocolException: content-length promised 598 bytes, but received 0

So it means that I'm not sending any data in my `POST`, how come?

Comment: you need to send your postData like con.getOutputStream().write(postData)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength));` you're just sending the lenght of your `postDataLength`, you're not actually setting it's body. In order to actually send your variable to the webservice you need to do this before calling the `connect()`:

```
OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
os.write(urlParameters.getBytes("UTF-8"));
os.close();
```

Comment: That what i thought, body sent was empty. Thank you for you time.

Comment: @BeGreen No problem! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need do this:

```
            body = datos.toString();
            content_bytes = body.getBytes("UTF-8");
            content_length = content_bytes.length;



            // establecer headers.
            connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8" );
            connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( content_length  ) );
```

.....

```
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
            dataOutputStream.write(body.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your answer to elaborate a bit on how this code works and how it will solve the problem. Thank you!